# How to apply a mask to a String?

Tags: java, string, masking

Hi I have a credit card number as a String. I need to apply a mask to hide the CC number:

I have "123-123-123" and I need to get something like "123-XXX-123"

Is there any elegant way to do this? I'm trying to avoid using severals substring() functions...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

`myCCStr = myCCStr.replaceFirst("-[0-9]{3}-", "-XXX-");`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this using PADLeft and PADRight functions of String class.

Comment: +0: which language are you referring to?

Comment: Maybe you are talking about `leftPad` and `rightPad` methods of `org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils`